# Automate the export of Facebook Insights data

Tags: excel, csv, export, odata, facebook-insights

I'm looking for a way of programmatically exporting Facebook insights data for my pages, in a way that I can automate it. Specifically, I'd like to create a scheduled task that runs daily, and that can save a CSV or Excel file of a page's insights data using a Facebook API. I would then have an ETL job that puts that data into a database.

I checked out the oData service for Excel, which appears to be broken. Does anyone know of a way to programmatically automate the export of insights data for Facebook pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to write something that uses the [Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) part of the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).  I haven't seen something already written for this.

Comment: Well if you come across something that does this, please let me know!

Answer (score 4):

It's possible and not too complicated once you know how to access the insights.

Here is how I proceed:

- Login the user with the offline_access and read_insights.
  read_insights allows me to access the insights for all the pages and applications the user is admin of.
  offline_access gives me a permanent token that I can use to update the insights without having to wait for the user to login.
- Retrieve the list of pages and applications the user is admin of, and store those in database.
- When I want to get the insights for a page or application, I don't query FQL, I query the Graph API: First I calculate how many queries to graph.facebook.com/[object_id]/insights are necessary, according to the date range chosen. Then I generate a query to use with the Batch API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/). That allows me to get all the data for all the available insights, for all the days in the date range, in only one query.
- I parse the rather huge json object obtained (which weight a few Mb, be aware of that) and store everything in database.
- Now that you have all the insights parsed and stored in database, you're just a few SQL queries away from manipulating the data the way you want, like displaying charts, or exporting in CSV or Excel format.

I have the code already made (and published as a temporarily free tool on [www.social-insights.net](http://www.social-insights.net)), so exporting to excel would be quite fast and easy.

Let me know if I can help you with that.
It can be done before the week-end.

Comment: Facebook provides "Post Level Data" in excel format via the Dashboard. Can this be automated. Did anybody ever do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://megalytic.com.  This is a service that exports FB Insights (along with Google Analytics, Twitter, and some others) to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

A new tool is available: the Analytics Edge add-ins now have a Facebook connector that makes downloads a snap.
http://www.analyticsedge.com/facebook-connector/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways that you could do this. I would suggest your choice depends on two factors:

1. What is your level of coding skill?
2. How much data are you looking to move?

I can't answer 1 for you, but in your case you aren't moving that much data (in relative terms). I will still share three options of many.

**HARD CODE IT**

This would require a script that accesses Facebook's GraphAPI
AND a computer/server to process that request automatically.
I primarily use AWS and would suggest that you could launch an EC2
and have it scheduled to launch your script at X times. I haven't used AWS Pipeline, but I do know that it is designed in a way that you can have it run a script automatically as well... supposedly with a little less server know-how

**USE THIRD PARTY ADD-ON**

There are a lot of people who have similar data needs. It has led to a number of easy-to-use tools. I use [Supermetrics Free](http://supermetrics.com/product/supermetrics-for-google-drive/) to run occasional audits and make sure that our tools are running properly. Supermetrics is fast and has a really easy interface to access Facebooks API's and several others. I believe that you can also schedule refreshes and updates with it.

**USE THIRD PARTY FULL-SERVICE ETL**
There are also several services or freelancers that can set this up for you at little to no work on your own. Depending on where you want the data. [Stitch](https://www.stitchdata.com/) is a service I have worked with on FB-ads. There might be better services, but it has fulfilled our needs for now.

### MY SUGGESTION

You would probably be best served by using a third-party add-on like Supermetrics. It's fast and easy to use. The other methods might be more worth looking into if you had a lot more data to move, or needed it to be refreshed more often than daily.

Comment: @AjeetShah I am not sure how I missed your comment so long ago. But, thanks for the request. I have since updated my response.